# Birt report parameter passing

Tags: oracle, birt

Hi i have to pass parameter to a report...with a concat-date ....but its showing error...
like this...am having in list box with 2011-2012,2012-2013...here is my oracle query

```
DATE FOMART IN DATABASE:25-Mar-2012 

oracle query
select tran_date,
ROUND (nvl(sum(WALKIN_WITHOUT_CGROUP),0)/ COUNT(*),2)APC
from OUTLET_PAYMODE_REPORT_FACT 

Before Open:
var sqld= new String();
yearParam = params["Year"].value;
yearParam = yearParam.split("-");
startYear = yearParam[0];
endYear = yearParam[1];

this.queryText =this.queryText +" where TRAN_DATE between '" + startYear + "01-Mar-' and '" + endYear + "30-Mar-'"+
"group by tran_date"
```

but am getting error like this.....

```
 org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.JDBCException: SQL statement does not return a ResultSet object.
SQL error #1:ORA-01861: literal does not match format string
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, your sql string should be

```
" where TRAN_DATE between '01-Mar-" + startYear + 
                   "' and '30-Mar-" + endYear + "' " + 
"group by tran_date"
```

Comment: now i run with u r code but giving error like this...    java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01841: (full) year must be between -4713 and +9999, and not be 0

Comment: @user2746120, can you check if you are setting values correctly for startYear and endYear in your split code? It looks like they are not getting set correctly.